# Syncing contacts regarding Android, vCard & Exchange

Tags: sync, android, exchange, vcard

My aim:

To import a list of contacts in the format of a vCard (`.vcf`) file into sync with a cloud server using Microsoft Exchange, for use with an Android device.

My problem:

The bunch of contacts from the vCard doesn't seem to be added to the to-sync-with-cloud queue: they seem to be skipped even at "sync now".

---

My actual scenario:

I copied this vCard file onto my Galaxy Nexus, then *clicked on it* (the the Gmail app, actually). Through the People app, I chose to import the bunch of contacts into my desired Exchange account. Well, that bunch of contacts didn't go up to the cloud. Instead, those contacts seem to stay on the device:

I have about 1000 contacts listed in the vCard file, but only about one or two seconds after I pressed the "sync now" button, the rotating-syncing-icon stopped rotating and disappeared. Also when I check on my cloud server's web interface, the contacts weren't there. I repeated the process quite a lot of times, but the phenomena seem to stay the same.

So how am I supposed to make my device/cloud think that the fresh bunch of contacts should be added to sync?

---

What made it worse for me was that there doesn't seem to be an easy way to bulk delete that bunch of contacts. I'd be glad to know a way to bulk delete contacts too.

Comment: Does the "cloud server using Microsoft Exchange" have a web interface to import the vCards?

Comment: @DBZ_A Yes I think so - I think that's how I ended up dealing with it. Can't remember for sure now; it's been a while.